# Are There Agile Processes For Agency Type Work? Scheduling Question

Tags: resources, project-management, scheduling, multiple-projects

I have just moved to a company where the production team is 15 strong, and consists of a mixture of back end and front end developers, testers & creatives. The team are working on multiple projects at the same time. Its agency work, so projects are fairly small, a CMS corporate website, a basic e-commerce site, that sort of thing.

At the moment the Project Managers make weekly resource requests for greater than 6 hours to be added to a long term production schedule, which runs as far as 6 weeks ahead. This is then transferred on a Friday into a short term schedule for the coming week. Added to this are requests of less than 6 hrs. If we are short in resource, we get in freelancers which are costly.

There are a lot of changes that happen to this weekly plan. Work get's pulled on the day it happens due to a dependency not being met, or another priority project coming in. The client doesn't get creative to us in time etc.

Partly there is a lot of bad planning going on, so I can start there. Although, I've been researching into what the ideal pipeline/work schedule should look like, and can't find anything for agile that applies to this structure.

Does anyone know if there are agile theories for agency type work?

Answer (score 0):

In general, SCRUM will work for this sort of work load. The only difference is that you may have to modify it a little bit so that you can group tasks related to a particular project into the same sprints so that you are not constantly switching projects for every task.

On the up-side, it seems like you are already doing weekly sprints, so it shouldn't be a hard transition.

Lastly, if it seems like there is too much churn going on for a 1-week sprint cycle (you mentioned the "fire fight" mentality causing issues currently), you might want to try 1/2 week sprints.

Answer (score 0):

Kanban would be an easy fit. It is a Lean-Agile approach that allows steady flow and recurring stuff (e.g., recurring planning, recurring demos and releases, recurring retrospectives, whatever, as desired), but because it's flow-based and just-in-time, it's PERFECT for situations where priority changes daily or there's lots of firefighting.

To start Kanban, you could keep your current process and workflow, begin a few practices (visualize work by workflow state on a big poster/board or electronic tool, put work-in-progress limits on each workflow state, and have regular retrospective meetings to continuously improve the process.

Lean and Kanban talk a lot about queuing theory and theory of constraints. The idea to planning is to only plan as much as you need. In a perfect world you would only ever need to know the next-highest priority item, because if you do too much batch planning (or batch anything, hence the WIP limits) that could be considered inventory, which is waste.

Kanban allows prioritizing by things such as urgent customer need, deadline (e.g., penalty if date is missed), normal work, etc., using classes of service and service-level agreements.

For example, issues that are blocking a customer are #1 priority, and might even cause us to exceed WIP limits and switch from in-progress work to satisfy. Such work will be done within 3 days 90% of the time. (Such agreements should be derived from real data, which you'll start to accumulate if you record item state each day, e.g., in a cumulative flow diagram.)

Along with classes of service and SLA's, you can also stipulate that 20% of the team's time should be spent on these urgent ("expedited") issues, 60% on normal work (feature development, for example), and perhaps 20% on continuous improvement, hygiene, technical stories, etc.